# How do I trigger bootstrap modal with a string that is in a script?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, bootstrap-modal, materialize

I have a time picker of which after I set the time, I want a pop up to appear with a message saying: "Time set to x-time". I want to achieve this by triggering the modal after clicking on set. This is the string "set" that can be seen in the script. 
Am I approaching this issue correctly? Or is there another way?

```
<div class="row menu_page">
    <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
    <div class="col s12 m6">
        <h3>Time Picker</h3>
        <form>
            <div class="input-field">
                <input type="text" id="time" class="timepicker" >
                <label for="time">Set time</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <div class="col s12 m3"></div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
    const timer = $(".timepicker");
    M.Timepicker.init(timer,{
        showClearBtn:true,
        twelveHour: false,
        i18n:{
            clear: "remove",
            cancel: "cancel",
            done: "set",
        }
    });
    timer.on("change",function(e){
        console.log("init js");
        const now = new Date()
        now.setHours(time.M_Timepicker.hours)
        now.setMinutes(time.M_Timepicker.minutes)
        API.post("settings/time",{new_time: now.getTime()})
    });
    $( "#time" ).change(function() {
        console.log("time is set!");
        // $('#exampleModal').modal('options'); 


    });

</script>
```

Comment: I can't see a modal anywhere?

Comment: My mistake. I have edited the code now

Comment: is this materialize? or is this bootstrap? are you using two frameworks??

Comment: @ImmortalDude yes, I'm using both frameworks.

Comment: Its a bad idea to use two frameworks, it may cause issues

Comment: I can imagine but luckily everything is still working fine at the moment.